Unable to make streaming mysql enterprise image backup to the remote host
I am unable to make a streaming MySQL database image backup to a remote host using ssh. The backup is expected to happen on the remote host, but it is happening to localhost only.
Here is my command:
mysqlbackup -u*** -p*** --socket=*** --backup-image=/tmp --backup-dir=*** backup-to-image |\
 ssh test@test.net "cat > /data/my_backup.img"

I used this page as a reference.
MySQL server and enterprise backup version: 8.0.39
What am I doing wrong?

To redirect the backup output to the terminal you need to use --backup-image=-, as shown in the documentation page you link to.

I am getting below error while using said option.
RROR: File_write operation failed for file '-', fd 12. Error code: 32, Broken pipe
Below is my try
mysqlbackup -uroot -p****** --socket=//mysql1.sock --backup-image=- backup-to-image --backup-dir=///3010 | ssh test@btest.net "cat > /****/my_backup.img"
Apart from this, i can see directory by name 3010 is getting created on local host
